# If every eigenvector of $\Phi + \Phi^{*}$ is also an eigenvector of $\Phi - \Phi^{*}$, $\Phi$ is normal.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be an inner product space with finite dimension and $\Phi: V \rightarrow V$ a homomorphism. If every eigenvector of $\Phi+\Phi^{*}$ is also an eigenvector of $\Phi-\Phi^{*}$, how can we conclude that $\Phi$ must be normal?

My thoughts on this:
Let $v \in V$ be an eigenvector of $\Phi + \Phi^{*}$. Therefore, $(\Phi + \Phi^{*})(v) = \lambda v$ and for the same $v$, $(\Phi - \Phi^{*})(v) = \mu v$ with eigenvalues $\lambda, \mu$. Now, assuming $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are non-zero, and $\mu \neq \lambda$, we can set up the following equations:
$$
\frac{(\Phi + \Phi^{*})(v)}{\lambda} = \frac{(\Phi - \Phi^{*})(v)}{\mu} 
\Leftrightarrow 
\frac{\lambda + \mu}{\lambda - \mu} \Phi^{*}(v) = \Phi(v) 
$$
It follows that $\Phi^{*}$ and $\Phi$ share all eigenvectors. However, V is not necessarily (or a subspace of) $\mathbb{C}$, so $\Phi$ may be non-triagonalizable. If it were triagonalizable or diagonalizable, it would be easy to show that $\Phi$ and $\Phi^*$ commute.

Another observation:

It is true, that $\Phi + \Phi^{*}$ is hermitian, as $(\Phi + \Phi^{*})^{*} = \Phi^{*} + \Phi = \Phi + \Phi^{*}$.
It is also true, that $\Phi - \Phi^{*}$ is skew-hermitian, as $(\Phi - \Phi^{*})^{*} = \Phi^{*} - \Phi = -\left(\Phi - \Phi^{*}\right)$.

It follows that $(\Phi + \Phi^{*}) \circ (\Phi + \Phi^{*})^{*} = (\Phi + \Phi^{*})^{*} \circ (\Phi + \Phi^{*})$, so it is normal.

Similarly, $(\Phi - \Phi^{*}) \circ (\Phi - \Phi^{*})^{*} = -(\Phi - \Phi^{*})^{*} \circ -(\Phi - \Phi^{*}) = (\Phi - \Phi^{*})^* \circ (\Phi - \Phi^{*})$, so it is also normal.

Comment: You need both $\lambda\neq 0$, $\mu\neq 0$, *and* $\lambda\neq\mu$ to be able to set up the equations you set up.

Comment: $V$ needs to be not just a vector space but an inner-product space in order for $\Phi + \Phi^*$ to make sense here

Comment: @BenGrossmann You are right, I forgot to specify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline of an Approach:** For convenience, denote $H = \Phi + \Phi^*$ and $K = \Phi - \Phi^*$.

1. From the fact that all eigenvectors of $H$ are eigenvectors of $K$ together with the fact that $H$ is Hermitian and hence diagonalizable, conclude that $H\circ K = K\circ H$.
2. From there, conclude that
   $$
   \frac{H + K}{2} \circ  \frac{H - K}{2} = \frac{H - K}{2} \circ  \frac{H + K}{2} \implies 
   \Phi \circ \Phi^* = \Phi^* \circ \Phi
   $$

Comment: The key idea I was missing was that the shared eigenvectors make the $K$ and $H$ commute.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\Phi+\Phi^*$ is self-adjoint, and therefore orthogonally diagonalizable. Thus, there is an (orthonormal) basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $\Phi+\Phi^*$. Therefore, the same is true of $\Phi-\Phi^*$, since that same basis also consists of eigenvectors of $\Phi-\Phi^*$.

Next, note that if $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $\Phi+\Phi^*$ (or of $\Phi-\Phi^*)$, then it is also an eigenvector of both $\Phi$ and $\Phi^*$: indeed, if $(\Phi+\Phi^*)(\mathbf{v})=\lambda\mathbf{v}$ and $(\Phi-\Phi^*)(\mathbf{v})=\mu\mathbf{v}$, then
$$\Phi(\mathbf{v}) = \left(\frac{(\Phi+\Phi^*)+(\Phi-\Phi^*)}{2}\right)(\mathbf{v}) = \left(\frac{\lambda+\mu}{2}\right)\mathbf{v},$$
and symmetrically $\Phi^*(\mathbf{v}) = \left(\frac{\lambda-\mu}{2}\right)\mathbf{v}$.

Therefore, the orthonormal basis of $V$ that consists of eigenvectors of $\Phi+\Phi^*$ also consists of eigenvectors of $\Phi$. Thus, $\Phi$ is orthogonally diagonalizable, and therefore must be normal.